# Custom action bar with tabs wish to be at the bottom in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm doing my project which is based on action bar tabs....I encountered with a problem.....it is

1.My requirement is i need to place 4 tabs at the bottom of the screen whenever I'm clicking the tab the view should be change.
2.So at first i choose tabs for this but i got to know that tabs are deprecated.
3.So i have chosen action bar with tabs and for view i have chosen fragments .
4.Still now every thing is fine and perfect.
5.But what i need is i need to place those tabs at the bottom.
6.And exactly i need tab view i tried split action bar for this but it doesn't appear to the tab view.
7.So dear developers can you please help me for this

I think i have given valid information .If you feel it as insufficient please let me know

Answer (score 0):

While ActionBar has a manifest attribute: `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` this won't work always, not for tabs.

The other option you have is to use a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)  with a [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). This will make swipe-able pages from fragment. Now you can include [`PagerTabStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) or [`PagerTitleStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) in Activity layout, inside `<ViewPager>` tag, at top or at bottom by using `android:layout-gravity` attribute on it.

This will show and switch to fragment/page titles.